# Squeeze Theorem conclusion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $\alpha(x) =- x$ and $\omega (x) =x$ and $\alpha(x)\leq f(x) \leq \omega (x)$ on $[0,1]$ then does the Squeeze Theorem conclude that $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[0,1]$?

My attempt: Suppose it is. Then by the Squeeze Theorem for integrals $\int_0^1 (\omega-\alpha)= 2 \int_0^1 x<\epsilon$. But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Edit: I changed my approach but I'm still stuck. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't really understand this question: what is it that you want to prove, anyway? That the function $\;x\sin x\;$ is **not** Riemann integrable in $\;[0,1]\;$ ? But it is, you know, and it also is continuous at zero.

Comment: Watch it: that all continuous function are RI does **not** mean that a RI functions *has* to be continuous. In fact, it can have infinite discontinuities...but perhaps we'll have to wait until measure theory to learn this.

Comment: Oh shoot you're right! I wasn't thinking of the right function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not hold as it is. For example, the function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c l}x,& x\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q\\0,&x\in[0,1]\cap(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)\end{array}\right.$$ satisfies your condition, but it's not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

Squeeze theorem as I know it is related to limits and says that if $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ in a certain neighborhood of $x=a$ (except possibly at $x=a$) and $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}h(x) = L$$ then we must have $$\lim_{x \to a}g(x) = L$$ For Riemann integrals there is a similar result namely that if $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ for $x \in [a, b]$ and $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx = \int_{a}^{b}h(x)\,dx = I$$ then $g(x)$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ and $$\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx = I$$ but as you can see the integrals of both $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ must be equal. This is not the case here ($\int_{0}^{1}\alpha(x)\,dx \neq \int_{0}^{1}\omega(x)\,dx$)so the squeeze theorem does not apply.